# In jsp page body onload function does not work from jquery dialog box loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working in jQuery dialog box and jsp page here my problem is when I click the button from the parent window jQuery dialog box will be opened there after I have load the body onload function in child window, but in child window the body onload functionality does not work only jQuery dialog ui only shown anybody help me?

**Parent window is:**

```
<a id="composeeditors" href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="callRequirementParsingInfo();">Send</a>
```

**jQuery code is:**

```
$('#composeeditors').load("/jsp/parsing.jsp?",function(){
    $('#compose_editor').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        position: ['center',150]
    });
});
```

**Child window is:**

```
<div id="compose_editor" data-options="title:'Requirement Parsing Informations'" style="padding:0px;width:700px; height:600px; overflow:auto;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the open or create event instead:

http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-open

Comment: I have opened the jquery dialog box , in that box i need to show details based on the body onload functionality, my problem is how to body onload while open the jquery dialog?

Comment: There simply is no "body onload" event fired when jQuery UI dialogs are shown because they load inside your document body. You need to use a different event, and a good choice is open or create, depending on your needs.

Comment: problem is not resolved ..still i trying to find the answer, because if body onload function is work only my task is completed

Comment: Couldn't you just switch your functionality from body onload to dialog open -event? Please check this code snippet: http://jsfiddle.net/AXLTc/1/

Comment: of course, the problem is solved if we write code inside body tag. but body onload doest work if you call from jquery to jsp or html file